# Motivation for studying compass and straightedge constructions?

Tags: soft-question, euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the (mathematical) point of geometric constructions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22686/what-is-the-mathematical-point-of-geometric-constructions)

Are there good motivations to study compass and straightedge constructions?

More specifically I want to know:

1) Are there good motivations to study compass and straightedge constructions in high school?

2) Are there good motivations to study compass and straightedge constructions in algebra courses in university (e.g. squaring the circle problem)

3) What was the original motivation of the ancient greek to study compass and straightedge constructions?

In each case the point is: Why should one restrict oneself to compass and straightedge only?