# Importance of construction of polygons

Tags: geometry, geometric-construction, polygons

Why did the ancient Greeks give so much importance to the construction of regular polygons with $n$-sides using only ruler and compass and tried to study for what $n$ was such a construction possible? Until Gauss-Wantzel, this was a famous open problem in Euclidean geometry.

Can anyone throw any light on its importance?

Comment: +1 Nice one! This never occurred to me, "we're gonna construct everything using only compass and straightedge, let's go," that's a weird motivation.

Comment: I wouldn't say particularly that the Greeks gave these constructions "so much importance", but I just think it was a natural problem to consider in plane geometry. If what you're after is some sort of practical application of these constructions I am not aware of any. The Greeks were probably considering such objects in the vein of "pure mathematics". It's kind of like asking why Fermat's last theorem was so important.

Comment: If one can speculate, the regular pentagon and its close relative the pentagram were of symbolic importance to the Pythagoreans. The division of a line segment in mean and extreme ratio (golden ratio) can be done by straightedge and compass, giving a construction of the regular pentagon. And in mathematics, once a problem becomes attractive, there is an urge to generalize. Also, the importance to Greek mathematicians of the construction of regular polygons is perhaps overstated. They decidedly did **not** restrict constructions to straightedge and compass.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22686/what-is-the-mathematical-point-of-geometric-constructions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The straight line and the circle suggest themselves as very basic objects in the study of geometry, so it's natural to see what you can do with a straightedge and a compass. The Greeks quickly worked out how to construct regular polygons with $3$, $4$, $5$, and $6$ sides, so again it must have seemed natural to speculate on what other polygons were constructible. I doubt the problem started out as being important; I think its importance came from its centuries-long resistance to solution.

Answer (score 2):

It's worth mentioning that many of the great Greek geometers, including Archimedes of Syracuse and Apollonius of Perga, used the [neusis ruler](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neusis_construction#section_2) unapologetically.  With this marked ruler, they were able to trisect arbitrary angles and, equivalently, solve cubic equations.  This did allow for the construction of the regular heptagon, for example.