# Is it possible to construct a regular heptagon with just compass and straightedge?

Tags: geometry, polygons, geometric-construction

Is it possible to construct a regular heptagon (a figure with seven sides) with just compass and straightedge? If so, could you please give me directions for how to do this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heptagon#Construction

Comment: [Relevant wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_polygon).

Comment: Pentagon: constructible. Heptagon: not constructible (but half the side length for an inscribed equilateral triangle is a good approximation for the side length of the inscribed heptagon).

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Apparently, a regular heptagon is constructible using a _marked_ straightedge.

Comment: @Arthur: or a trisectrix of Hippias, sure.

Comment: Why do people provide "simple" answers as comments instead of proper answers? It seems like a form of "modesty", but it makes a lot of things harder (among other things, it shows the question among the unanswered ones).

Answer (score 4):

No, [it's not possible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_polygon); in fact, the regular heptagon is the regular polygon with the least number of sides that is impossible to construct with compass and straightedge alone. It is, however, possible to construct it [using a neusis ruler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neusis_construction). A related question has been asked (and answered) [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/360068/importance-of-construction-of-polygons).

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. Because $7=2*3+1$, and there is a factor of 3 in there, you will need to trisect and angle in order to get an exact construction, something not possible with compass and straightedge alone.

The minimal polynomial for any compass&straightedge constructible number must have a degree that is a power of two (quadratic, fourth order, eighth order, 16th order, *et cetera*). Whereas the minimal polynomial for $\cos\frac{2\pi}{7}$ is $8x^3+4x^2-4x-1$.

And here is $\cos\frac{2\pi}{7}$ in expanded form:

$\displaystyle\cos\frac{2\pi}{7}=\frac{\sqrt[3]{\frac{7-21i\sqrt{3}}{2}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{7+21i\sqrt{3}}{2}}-1}{6}.$

Here, the complex numbers in the numerator, when added, cancel out each other's imaginary parts leaving behind a real expression. Note that you CANNOT get rid of the complex numbers in the numerator, as the minimal polynomial that I pointed out earlier is *casus irreducibilis.*

And it doesn't end there. In fact, when dividing arbitrary angles into anything that isn't a power of two, a lot of times you will end up having to take cube roots, 5th roots, 7th roots, *et cetera* of complex numbers, which you cannot remove from the expression without introducing trigonometric functions. For example, while a regular pentagon is fairly easy to construct with compass and straightedge, constructing a regular 25-gon requires you to use an Archimedean spiral or something else in order to divide a 72° angle into five 14.4° angles. And the resulting expression for $\cos 14.4^\circ$?

$\displaystyle\cos14.4^\circ=\frac{\sqrt[5]{-1+\sqrt{5}-i\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}}+\sqrt[5]{-1+\sqrt{5}+i\sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}}}{2\sqrt[5]{4}}.$